# Make Makefile to build newly created file

Tags: c, makefile

I have Makefile below that should build all new *.c files I will place in current folder. But this not happens. I have created new file with name `mouse_cursor_icon.c` and place in the same folder together with `main_btn.c`. I was expecting make command will build and generate `mouse_cursor_icon.o` file. But this not happened. How to solve that?

```
#
# Makefile
#
CC ?= gcc
LVGL_DIR_NAME ?= lvgl
LVGL_DIR ?= ${shell pwd}
CFLAGS ?= -O3 -g0 -I$(LVGL_DIR)/ -Wall -Wshadow -Wundef -Wmaybe-uninitialized -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-discarded-qualifiers -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-function -Wundef -Wno-error=strict-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-error=cpp -Wuninitialized -Wmaybe-uninitialized -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wtype-limits -Wsizeof-pointer-memaccess -Wno-format-nonliteral -Wno-cast-qual -Wunreachable-code -Wno-switch-default -Wno-switch-enum -Wreturn-type -Wmultichar -Wformat-security -Wno-ignored-qualifiers -Wno-error=pedantic -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-error=missing-prototypes -Wdouble-promotion -Wclobbered -Wdeprecated -Wempty-body -Wtype-limits -Wshift-negative-value -Wstack-usage=1024 -Wno-unused-value -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wuninitialized -Wmaybe-uninitialized -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wtype-limits -Wsizeof-pointer-memaccess -Wno-format-nonliteral -Wpointer-arith -Wno-cast-qual -Wmissing-prototypes -Wunreachable-code -Wno-switch-default -Wswitch-enum -Wreturn-type -Wmultichar -Wno-discarded-qualifiers -Wformat-security -Wno-ignored-qualifiers -Wno-sign-compare
LDFLAGS ?= -lm
BIN = demo


#Collect the files to compile
MAINSRC = ./main_btn.c

include $(LVGL_DIR)/lvgl/lvgl.mk
include $(LVGL_DIR)/lv_drivers/lv_drivers.mk
include $(LVGL_DIR)/lv_examples/lv_examples.mk

OBJEXT ?= .o

AOBJS = $(ASRCS:.S=$(OBJEXT))
COBJS = $(CSRCS:.c=$(OBJEXT))

MAINOBJ = $(MAINSRC:.c=$(OBJEXT))

SRCS = $(ASRCS) $(CSRCS) $(MAINSRC)
OBJS = $(AOBJS) $(COBJS)

## MAINOBJ -> OBJFILES

all: default

%.o: %.c
    @$(CC)  $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
    @echo "CC $<"
    
default: $(AOBJS) $(COBJS) $(MAINOBJ)
    $(CC) -o $(BIN) $(MAINOBJ) $(AOBJS) $(COBJS) $(LDFLAGS)

clean: 
    rm -f $(BIN) $(AOBJS) $(COBJS) $(MAINOBJ)
```

Comment: This entire makefile hinges on the value of `ASRCS` and `CSRCS` but you don't define them anywhere here.

Comment: Please read the documentation of Make, and some tutorial. A makefile "just" defines dependencies between files, and how to produce them. -- Your makefile does not show any rule to include all C sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normal make does not have any (good) way of saying "build all of the .c files in a directory."  GNU make has extensions that allow this sort of thing: it defines a `wildcard` function that can be used to get all the (source) files that match some pattern.  For example, you might add to your Makefile:

```
CSRCS := $(wildcard ./*.c)
```

to set `$(CSRCS)` (which you use elsewhere and never define) to be all of the .c files in the current directory.